# Problems in running a modified Java code

Tags: java

I modified a Java code in Eclipse on my laptop with a Windows O.S. Now I have to run the code on a linux O.S. via SSH. I copied all the files and I tried to compile the code. The compilation went well, so there were no errors in the code. Anyway, when I tried to run it, the following errors appeared on the shell:

```
  [ac6411@epigenetic models]$ java TanaModel
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TanaModel (wrong name:     models/TanaModel)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

Do you know what kind of the problem is?I'm new in Java coding, so I don't know how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you compile the code on the Linux box? Is java set up correctly on it (try java -version)?

Comment: What is the name of file and class? (please be accurate with case)

Answer (score 2):

```
wrong name:     models/TanaModel
```

This means it expected to find TanaModel.class under the models directory, but found it somewhere else (maybe the current directory?). Put the class file in a the models directory, and run it as

```
java models.TanaModel
```

Java expects class files to be organized in directories that mirror the package structure you used in your source code.

Comment: I tried but it give me the following message: [ac6411@epigenetic models]$ java models.TanaModel Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/TanaModel

Comment: You're getting closer, then. Make sure the current directory (".") is part of your classpath (usually set up in the CLASSPATH environment variable).

Comment: I modified the CLASSPATH so that now it refers to the directory in which i put all the files but it gives me the same problem. Have you got ideas?

Comment: Please post your exact CLASSPATH and the command that you are using to  start your program. Remember also that CLASSPATH uses ":" in Unix and ";" in Windows.

Comment: This is the path:
PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local_machine/bin:/usr/local_machine/sbin:/home/ma/a/ac6411/bin:/home/ma/a/ac6411/Cairoli_Thesis:/home/ma/a/ac6411/Cairoli_Thesis:/home/ma/a/ac6411::/home/ma/a/ac6411/bin
This is the command line:
[ac6411@epigenetic models]$ java models.TanaModel
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/TanaModel
This is the path of the files where the code is put:
[ac6411@epigenetic models]$ pwd
/home/ma/a/ac6411/Cairoli_Thesis/tana_java/src/models

Comment: CLASSPATH, not PATH. Sorry, i have to go now, but you'll figure it out. Java is weird this way until you get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TanaModel (wrong name: models/TanaModel) at
```

What command did you run, I'm guessing `java TanaModel` ?
Most likely your TanaModel is declared to be in `package models;`

Try calling it like this:

```
java models.TanaModel
```

Comment: I tried but it give me the following message: [ac6411@epigenetic models]$ java models.TanaModel Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/TanaModel

Comment: Please post some more info about your code, directory/package layout and code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Eclipse security issue, this would help.

```
//Java Code

try 
{
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() 
    {
        public Object run() 
        {    
                 try 
                 {
                 // Insert code here to do required action (get or open file)
                 }
                 catch (Exception e) 
                 {
                 // Insert code to catch exception from trying to do above action
                 }
        }    
    }
    );
}
catch(Exception e)
{
// Insert code to catch failed doPrivileged()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run your program, try calling it like this:

`java models.TanaModel`

Comment: I tried but it give me the following message: [ac6411@epigenetic models]$ java models.TanaModel
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: models/TanaModel